# use <b-dropdown> in <b-collapse> cause DOM errors vue-bootstrap and nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, virtual-dom, bootstrap-vue

this is my code for nav menu :

```
<b-navbar toggleable="lg" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse" class="mx-auto my-0"></b-navbar-toggle>
  <b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
    <b-navbar-nav>
        <b-nav-item to="/">home</b-nav-item>
    </b-navbar-nav>
    <b-dropdown id="dropdown-1" text="categories">

        <b-dropdown id="dropdown-2" :text="category.title" v-for="category in settings.categories" 
        :key="category.id">
            <b-dropdown-item :to="`/category/`+child.id+`/`+child.slug"  v-for="child in 
            category.childs" :key="child.id">{{ child.title }}</b-dropdown-item>
        </b-dropdown>
    </b-dropdown>
  </b-collapse>
</b-navbar>
```

but i get so many DOM error in nuxt . i'm using bootstrap-vue . i want to use "b-dropdown" in nav bar but it cause DOM errors . how can i get rid of these errors ?

[image]

why i'm using "b-dropdown" in wrong place ? well , see this question : [bootstrap-vue multi level drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63357651/bootstrap-vue-multi-level-drop-down/63361501)

if i remove (b-dropdown id="dropdown-1" ... ) tag , errors will go away !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's not an error, it's a warning. It has to do with that component not being compatible with SSR so the server side content doesn't match the client side.

You should try wrapping the code between `<no-ssr/>` tags and that should make it work fine.

```html
<no-ssr>
<b-navbar toggleable="lg" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse" class="mx-auto my-0"></b-navbar-toggle>
  <b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
    <b-navbar-nav>
        <b-nav-item to="/">home</b-nav-item>
    </b-navbar-nav>
    <b-dropdown id="dropdown-1" text="categories">

        <b-dropdown id="dropdown-2" :text="category.title" v-for="category in settings.categories" 
        :key="category.id">
            <b-dropdown-item :to="`/category/`+child.id+`/`+child.slug"  v-for="child in 
            category.childs" :key="child.id">{{ child.title }}</b-dropdown-item>
        </b-dropdown>
    </b-dropdown>
  </b-collapse>
</b-navbar>
<no-ssr/>
```

For more information check this [github issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1700).

Answer (score -1):

It's a current bug in Bootstrap-Vue (version `2.14.0` to the current version `2.16.0`).
However based on this [comment](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5453#issuecomment-668978083), there's a workaround, which involves using a slot instead of the `text` prop.

So instead of this

```html
<b-dropdown text="Category" ... >
  <!-- Content -->
</b-dropdown>
```

You would write this

```html
<b-dropdown ... >
  <template v-slot:button-content>
    Category
  </template>

  <!-- Content -->
</b-dropdown>
```